# Definition of the exponential map for regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

> **Definition.** Let $M$ be a regular $C^2$-surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, $p\in M$ and
> $$T_p^1M=\{e\in T_pM:\lVert e\rVert=1\}.$$
> be the unit circle in the tangent plane $T_pM$. Then every non-zero tangent vector $Z\in T_pM$ can be written as
> $$Z=r_Z\cdot e_Z,$$
> where $r_Z=\lVert Z\rVert$ and $e_Z=\frac{Z}{\lVert Z\rVert}\in T_p^1M$. For a unit tangent vector $e\in T_0^1M$ let
> $$\gamma_e:(-a_e,b_e)\to M$$
> be the unique maximal geodesic such that $a_e,b_e\in\mathbb{R}^+\cup\{\infty\}$, $\gamma_e(0)=p$, $\gamma'_e(0)=e$. It can be shown that the real number
> $$\varepsilon_p=\inf\{a_e,b_e:e\in T_p^1M\}$$
> is positive, so the open ball
> $$B_{\varepsilon_p}^2(0)=\{Z\in T_pM:\lVert Z\rVert<\varepsilon_p\}$$
> is non-empty. Then the exponential map $\exp_p:B_{\varepsilon_p}^2(0)\to M$ at $p$ is defined by
> $$\exp_p(Z)=\begin{cases}
> p,& Z=0,\\
> \gamma_{e_Z}(r_Z),& Z\neq 0.
> \end{cases}$$

I have been trying to understand the proof that shows that geodesics are locally the shortest paths between their endpoints. And I get most of it but I do not understand one point of the definition of the exponential map we use here:

Let $\gamma : (-a,b) \to M$ be the unique maximal geodesic such that $a,b$ are strictly positive or infinite, with $\gamma$ parametrized by arclength, $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=e$.

Why can we say that $\varepsilon = \inf\{a,b\}$ is going to be strictly positive?

I have been having a really hard time understanding this because for example :
Take $M$ the unit sphere and $p=(1,0,0)$. One could take $a$ to be a little bit bigger than $0$ and $b=2\pi-a$ and then one would get $\varepsilon=\inf\{a\}=0$.

Is there something I am misunderstanding or completely missing here?

I would be happy to get any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't have the time to write up a full answer right now (I could probably do it later), but the thing you're missing is that $\gamma$ is maximal. This means that $(-a,b)$ is the largest possible interval where $\gamma$ can be defined. In particular, $a$ and $b$ are uniquely defined, and not free for you to choose

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Is $M$ assumed _complete_ (e.g., compact)? If so, then "every geodesic is defined for all real $t$." If not, your intuition is correct. For example, if $M$ is the open unit disk, the unit geodesic flow is not globally defined in any open interval about $0$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you for the warm welcome! <> M is a regular surface, it is not assumed complete. I do not see how that changes anything for question though. I am wondering why would ε_p be positive and not 0. Sorry if I simply did not understand what you were implying.

Comment: It appears I misunderstood: What's true is, if we fix a point $p$ of $M$ and a unit tangent vector $v$ in $T_pM$, then there exists a maximal interval $(a, b)$ with $a < 0 < b$ on which the geodesic $\gamma$ satisfying $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$ is defined. (The point of my prior comment was, $a$ and $b$ depend on $p$ and $v$, and if $M$ is not complete the infimum of $|a|$ (and $|b|$) over $p$ and $v$ is $0$.) <> But from your clarification it appears you're asking "If $p$ and $v$ are fixed, how do we know $a < 0 < b$?" That's a formality about solutions of ODEs. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see. Thank you very much. I have not had ODEs class yet. It appears I was missing some basic knowledge about how their intervals are built. Especially for closed curves.